# Error in coloring us state [R]

Tags: r, dictionary, colors

I'm trying to create an Us map divided by States *(without Alaska and Hawaii)*. Each State should be colored based on a simple criterion.
I've a data set with all the States and a value indicating the investments. This are the first raws of my data:

```
         states investment   
    1      AL    5500000  
    2      AR    5000000  
    3      AZ   54947100 
    4      CA 3285330900 
    5      CO  135520000
```

- If the investment is equal to 0 *(indicating a missing value of the data set)*, the corresponding State should be colored in white.
- If the investment is greater than 0 and less than 5500000, the
  corresponding State should be colored in blue.
- If the investment is greater than 5500000, the corresponding State
  should be colored in green.

My data set is on an **excel** file, so I've used the `XLConnetc` package to load data in **R**. Then I've created a script which create a new column to store the colors

```
 dati["col"] <- NA
      for (i in 1:48){
       if(dati$investment[i] >0 && dati$investment[i] <= 5500000){
       dati$col[i] <- "blue"
       }
           if(dati$investment[i] > 5500000){
       dati$col[i] <- "green"
       }
       if(dati$investment[i] == 0){
       dati$col[i] <- "white"
       } 
      }
```

my new data set is now this:

```
      states investment   col
 1      AL    5500000    blue
 2      AR    5000000    blue
 3      AZ   54947100    green
 4      CA 3285330900    green
```

Now, I use the new column *(called `dati$col`)* in order to color my map. To create the map I use

```
 map("state", lty=1, lwd=1, fill=TRUE, boundary=TRUE, col = dati$col)
```

I've noticed some problems with the map. For example: Georgia should be green, instead in my map is blue; or South Carolina should be green, instead in the map is white

```
      states investment   col
 9      GA   46008000    green
 38     SC   14000000    green
```

This are only 2 examples of wrong color matching. 
Do you have any advice on what I might have been wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `state` built-in database in R has 63 polygons, whereas your `dati` data frame has only 50 (or fewer??) rows. So when you use `col=dati$col` R recycles `dati$col` when it runs out of rows. Not only that, the order of the rows in `dati` is alphabetical by state abbreviation, whereas the order of the polygons in the `state` database is alphabetical by state name (more or less). So the fact that you got as much agreement as you did is purely by accident.

```
polys <- map('state',plot=F,namesonly=T)
length(polys)
# [1] 63
head(polys,5)
# [1] "alabama"     "arizona"     "arkansas"    "california"  "colorado"
```

Note that the first 3 rows of `dati` are: AL, AR, AZ, which is *a different order* from the first three polygons.

So why are there 63 polygons?? Some states have (large) islands, which are treated as separate polygons. This creates a new problem, because the "name" of states with multiple polygons is non-standard. For example:

```
polys[substr(polys,1,8)=="new york"]
# [1] "new york:manhattan" "new york:main" "new york:staten island" "new york:long island"
```

So to create a merge field you need to parse these odd names.

One way to do this is to create a dataframe with rows for all the polygons in the `state` database, merge that with `dati` based on a common field, resort the result into the original order, and use that for the colors. It's a massive headache.

```
library(maps)
# example only: create df with state abbr, name, and population
dati <- data.frame(state=state.abb, 
                   name=tolower(state.name),
                   population=state.x77[,"Population"],
                   stringsAsFactors=F)
dati[dati$population<1000,]$population <- 0  # artificial zeros
# color by population, similar to OP's use case
dati$col                          <- "green" # most populous
dati[dati$population < 5000,]$col <- "blue"  # moderately populous
dati[dati$population == 0,]$col   <- "white" # least populous

polygons      <- data.frame(polyName=map("state",plot=F,namesonly=T))
polygons$id   <- 1:nrow(polygons)           # need this to restore original order
polygons$name <- gsub("(:+[a-z\ \']+)","",polygons$polyName)
polygons <- merge(polygons,dati, all.x=T)   # append color info
polygons <- polygons[order(polygons$id),]   # restore original order
map('state',fill=T,col=polygons$col)
```

[image]

This is precisely the reason I recommend using actual shapefiles with the `rgdal` package, and plotting with `ggplot`.